# SG300 Load balancing / distribution configuration

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, vlan, ipv4

I have a SG300-28p switch I want to connect 18 devices, but want to balance or distribute evenly the traffic between groups of six ports (1-6, 7-12, 13-18). I was hoping to have DHCP enabled for all ports (if configuring for VLAN 100,101,102 to the ports respectively).  Any advice for this configuration?  I'm hitting a brick wall (as I'm a newbie). (Background - want to connect multiple Raspberry PI's for data analysis - so will consume lots of traffic).

Comment: The traffic distribution will be dependent on the MAC address of the destination.  If all your traffic goes to one MAC address, it all goes to one port.  There's nothing to configure.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Switch Generally does not provide Load balancing capability for one single mac address. Switch find destination based on mac address. Device can have only one mac address or only ip address,

but switch provide ether channel. Ether channel is link aggregation or port channel architecture is being used.

But device have to have multiple interfaces. when you use ether channel it will create one logical interface combining multiple physical ports. You can use 2-8 ports in ether channel.

for more details [click Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherChannel)